# Why does the Visual Studio IDE Marshall a static value on the wrong thread but not do it at runtime?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, uwp, marshalling

I have an issue where my UWP User Controls cause an exception in (XAML) design mode because the thread is marshalled to the wrong thread? What I have is several controls that use the same Brush and it makes sense that they all use reference value rather than creating many new (same) brushes.

```
internal static Brush DefaultHighlightBrushStore = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.NavajoWhite);

internal static readonly Brush TransparentBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent);
```

When referenced from a control at desgin time, The above code causes the following error:
*System.Exception: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))*

An easy solution (see below) was to see if the control is in design mode but would like to understand why it was necessary, whether I have just encountered a bug in Visual Studio or my Brain is over tired and I am missing something simple.

Note: I do understand that this means they are not being marshalled onto the UI thread but my question is why - when they marshal correctly outside of the designer?

```
    private static bool DesignMode => Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled;

    private static Brush DefaultHighlightBrushStore = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.NavajoWhite);
    private static readonly Brush TransparentBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent);

    internal static Brush DefaultHighlightBrush
    {
        get
        {
            return DesignMode ? new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.NavajoWhite) : DefaultHighlightBrushStore;
        }

        set
        {
            DefaultHighlightBrushStore = value;
        }
    }

    internal static Brush Transparent
    {
        get
        {
            return DesignMode ? new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent) : TransparentBrush;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Microsoft added a lot of protections to prevent any exceptions that would cause a Blue Screen and stop the machine from running.  Who know what holes Microsoft found in the compiled code that warranted the error.  Normally adding an Invoke to the code will get around the issue.  The Invoke adds locking around the code to prevent cross thread errors.

Comment: @jdweng I was more interested in why it was marshalling to the wrong thread at design time rather than anything else. Thanks for your answer but as you can see from my original question that I already created a safe workaround.